# How to get jQuery DataTables to switch between multiple DOM tables?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I have a `<select>` and every time the user changes its selected option, I want a different jQuery Datatable to draw (using a hidden DOM `<table>` as the data source):

```
<!-- Assume I have included jquery.dataTables.css and jquery.dataTables.js correctly. -->

<style>
    #hidden-tables {
        display: hidden;
    }
</style>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#table1").dataTable();
        $("#table2").dataTable();
    });
</script>

<select id="my-sel">
    <option selected="selected" id="opt1">Nothing selected</option>
    <option id="opt1">Opt1</option>
    <option id="opt2">Opt2</option>
</select>

<div id="hidden-tables">
    <table id="table1">
        <!-- Omitted for brevity -->
    </table>
    <table id="table2">
        <!-- Omitted for brevity -->
    </table>
</div>

<!-- When the user selects opt1 or opt2 in the "my-sel" <select>, then display its corresponding table here. -->
<div id="table-to-show"></div>
```

Basically, when the page loads up, I want the `my-sel` select to be displaying "*Nothing selected*" and to have no tables drawn. When the user selects anything other than "*Nothing selected*", I want the appropriate jQuery DataTable to draw inside the `table-to-show` div. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

One solution could be something like

```
<div class="show">
    <table id="table1">
        <!-- Omitted for brevity -->
    </table>
</div>
<div class="hide">
    <table id="table2">
        <!-- Omitted for brevity -->
    </table>
</div>
```

where

```
.hide {display:none;}
```

and

```
.show {display:block;}
```

All you have to do is to toggle the classes when you choose the different options from the select drop down...

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

Replace this...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#table1").dataTable();
    $("#table2").dataTable();
});
</script>
```

With this..

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#my-sel').change(function () {
        var opt = $(this).find('option:selected').html();
        if (opt !== 'Nothing selected') {
            $('#table-to-show').html('');
            var tableName;
            switch (opt) {
                case 'Opt1':
                    tableName = 'table1';
                    break;
                case 'Opt2':
                    tableName = 'table2';
                    break;
            }
            $('#' + tableName).clone(true).appendTo('#table-to-show');
            $('#table-to-show table').dataTable();
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Also change your `display:hidden;` to `display:none;` 
"hidden" is used for css property "visible" not "display"

Hope that helps!